# How to set output file from another gradle build script's task from GradleBuild task?

Tags: gradle, build, output

I have project A with gradle build. I have another project B with gradle build also. I want to include project B's jar into project A's war. I can call project B's build script from project A's build script (see below).
But I can not set project B's jar as output file of task `buildB`.

Is there any way to set project B's jar (which is output file of task jar) as output file of task buildB?

```
task buildB(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = "../BProject/build.gradle"
    tasks = ["clean", "jar"]       // jar task produce xxx.jar as it's outputs.files

    // HERE, any script to set xxx.jar as outputs.files of task buildB???
}

war {
    from (buildB) {                // can not get xxx.jar from buildB
        into "WEB-INF/classes"
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to set up a multimodule project and define a `compile` dependency of type project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did.

/settings.gradle

```
include 'AProject', 'BProject'
```

/AProject/build.gradle

```
task buildB(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = "../BProject/build.gradle"
    tasks = ["clean", "jar"]       // jar task produce xxx.jar as it's outputs.files
}

war {
    dependsOn buildB
    doFirst {
        from (project(':BProject').tasks['jar']) {
            into "WEB-INF/classes"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if `BProject` is a simple one-module build, otherwise you would need to include all its dependencies (i.e. subprojects).

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to configure a [multi module](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) project and define a [*project*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:project_dependencies)-scope dependency.

Since the answer full answer will be lengthy, [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/43271608) you can find a demo that shows how it can be done.

The demo consists of two projects. One project is built to war and has a dependency to another project which is built to war. If you build **a** project, **b** will be built automatically and included as a jar.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Opal. But buildA does not depend on buildB's jar, it only use jar as downloadable resource. So it does not need to define project B as compile dependencies.  
But your answer and github source let me think about multi project, so I figuared out a solution. Thanks again!